# In C++ Trying to Run an EXE from a UNC in Windows 10. Very new to C++

Tags: c++, filesystems

I just started writing a console app in C++.  It does some verification and then it needs to find and run an executable that can be in a variety of places depending on how it was deployed.  So most of the script works and even the run part works depending on the OS and location.  If it is local it works and if it is windows 7 it seems to work even on the UNC.  But in Windows 10 it just exits out.

The script finds the exe and runs it from the path it is in.  It works when I created the application as a batch file the uses popD to move to the exe location for working directory but I can't seem to mimic that functionality in C++.  I have tried `SetCurrentDirectory` but it won't take my string that I am trying to pass.

```
if (version >= minver)
    {
        std::string name = "testApp.exe";
        std::string path = (fs::current_path().string());
        for (const auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
        {
            std::string list = entry.path().string();
            int found;
            if ((found = list.find(name)) !=list.npos)
            {
                std::cout << list << std::endl;
\\This is the part that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't
                system(list.c_str());

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `GetLastError()` is your friend.

Comment: As stated I am brand new to this.  So would I put that in right after the system() call?

Comment: execute your program in Debug mode and add breakpoints, or add some `cout` to identify when your program fail, `GetLastError()` must be called just after

Comment: I get a UNC Paths not supported but I get that on the Windows 7 machine too and it works.

Comment: Before executing C++ program on windows 10, try to open `command line interface` go to `testApp.exe` path, and try to run it. may be your `testApp.exe` is not compatible with Windows 10

Comment: Possibly if can set the list string as my current directory and just run the program?

Comment: What you understend by *and if it is local on the system it works* ? in the other case, you try to run program over network ?!

Comment: Yes.  Hard to explain, but the program can be deployed in a number of ways.  If it is local on the computer hte app works.  If it is running from a share it just fails.  I think it is because it is a console app and running from a share just fails.

Comment: it fails because of the Windows security policies setting

Comment: No I can run it using a batchfile with pushd I just don't know how to replicate that in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can start your program from console, try to use `CreateProcess` function in console mode:

```
int runProcessFromCmd( char* pcExecPath)
{

    if( NULL == pcExecPath)
    {
        printf("empty path!");
        return -1;
    }

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    memset( &si, 0, sizeof(si) );
    memset( &pi, 0, sizeof(pi) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    // Start child process from command line
    // First parameter = NULL => we use cmd
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL, pcExecPath, NULL,NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,    NULL, &si, &pi )) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed with error (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return -2;
    }

    // Wait child process 
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close all handles
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Comment: Landstalker thank you for all your help.  I was wrong about running from the console.  I can run from a batch file using PushD to move my working directory.  But I can't seem to mimic that functionality in c++

Comment: I have been trying to incorporate this into my code but I keep getting mismatches.  and other problems compiling.  I did finalyy get `ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", list.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` to run but it exited out without running on the test system too,

Comment: Is there a way to execute an exe without using cmd?

Answer (score 0):

So in the long run I was chasing down the problem in the wrong way.  Thanks to LandStalker for putting on a better path.  I was right about mimicking a popD but had a hard time doing it in the right way to actually work.
I `SetCurrentDirectory` and then did a `ShellExecute` on the program name.